# Azure KeyVault Managed Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, service-principal

I am trying to implement KeyVault managed Storage Account in Azure to rotate storage keys using KeyVault. I did follow the documentation, which uses both "ServicePrincipalID" and "UserPrincipalID", but in my case i am provisioning my resources and implementing all the steps involved using my service principal (as we deploy using VSTS with service principal) and using "ServicePrincipalID" as ObjectID in place of "UserPrincipalID" (as there is no user intervention during provisioning and post-provisioning process). I did give my service principal "Owner" role and all required permissions for keyvault to access storage. But when i do "Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount" i get the below error which says "KeyVault is unable to perform the action on behalf of the caller". So i am not sure what access i am still missing, even after making my principal as Owner. Please find my screenshots below for more details. Would be glad to hear any suggestions to cross this hurdle.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3SPh.png)
[KeyVault details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIjW7.png)

Thanks
Chaitanya Alladi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i get the below error which says "KeyVault is unable to perform the action on behalf of the caller". So i am not sure what access i am still missing, even after making my principal as Owner.

**Unfortunly**, we can't do that with service principle now. 
AAD doesn't support get OBO(OnBehalfOf) token for service principle caller tokens.

We need to use the **user credentials instead of Service Principal credentials**. There are some operations that are only possible **on behalf of the user and not  Service Principal** when it comes to storage account keys as of now.

Comment: Thanks @TomSun for the clarification. Do you think it will be made available to use Service Principal (which might be a better way i believe) anytime soon?

Comment: I agree with you that it is better that we could use Service Principal to do  that. Sorry, I don't know when it will be released.